# Equivalent of try catch(exception handling) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there an equivalent of try catch mechanism for client side(JavaScript) like the one we have for exception handling in C#.

What would be the best way to handle exceptions in client side.

Comment: maybe [try ... catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: I tried looking for a suitable reason to close this down, but there isn't one.

Comment: Try `try {}catch(e){}` then you can catch it

Comment: Actually, "looking for a resource" is the best fit.

Comment: Sorry for this. Just now downloaded the new iOS app and was excited to try it out. I apologise for this. Will delete this post

Comment: wow iOS and javascript are the same , your sharing your account with someone or they gave it to you, as your words do not match your history on questions

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. What I meant was I just downloaded the alpha version of stack exchange app and was too tempted to try it out. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript error handling with try .. catch .. finally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286297/javascript-error-handling-with-try-catch-finally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try
  {
  //Run some code here
  }
catch(err)
  {
  //Handle errors here
  }
```

You can also throw exceptions as in c#

```
throw 'something went wrong !';
```

The exception can be a JavaScript String, a Number, a Boolean or an Object.