# How does a try..finally for loop with continue work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Here is the example from You Don't Know JS:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    try {
        continue;
    }
    finally {
        console.log( i );
    }
}
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

How is it able to print all numbers if continue makes the loop jump over that iteration? To add to that, "console.log(i) runs at the end of the loop iteration but before i++" which should explain why it prints from 0 to 9?

Comment: `fnally` ALWAYS runs after its corresponding `try..catch` segment ends. `continue` ends the `try` at which point `finally` goes "hang on a minute, do this first!" and logs `i` before the `continue` is allowed to proceed.

Comment: For another example, try `function test() {try {return 'foo';} finally {console.log('bar');}}` and you'll see that code after an unconditional `return` isn't necessarily dead.

Comment: No matter what , finally block will be executed before going over to next iteration in for loop. 
Also, in for loop you told "set 'i' to zero, then increment it until it's incrementation is lower than 10, then stop".
So , when it goes to number 10 it will result in break statement of loop.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol why dont you put it in an answer so we can upvote it correctly :O

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript error handling with try .. catch .. finally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286297/javascript-error-handling-with-try-catch-finally)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact in a `try ... catch` statement, `finally` block will always be reached and executed.

So here in your case:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    try {
        continue;
    }
    finally {
        console.log( i );
    }
}
```

The `finally` block will be executed every iteration whatever you do in the `try` block, that's why all the numbers were printed.

**Documentation:**

You can see from the [**MDN try...catch Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) that:

> The finally clause contains statements to execute after the try block and catch clause(s) execute, but before the statements following the try statement. The finally clause executes regardless of whether or not an exception is thrown. If an exception is thrown, the statements in the finally clause execute even if no catch clause handles the exception.

Answer (score 1):

[Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#The_finally_clause):

> The finally clause contains statements to execute after the try block
>   and catch clause(s) execute, but before the statements following the
>   try statement. The finally clause executes regardless of whether or
>   not an exception is thrown. If an exception is thrown, the statements
>   in the finally clause execute even if no catch clause handles the
>   exception.

So finally is always called after the catch statement.